# PHPUnit test method is called once with each argument

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a method which will be called multiple times during a single test but only once with each argument. So I want to test that the method only received each argument once. For example, I have here a mkdir function that is called with each directory to create:

The test

```
$dirs = [
    "$parentDir/$siteName/assets/components",
    "$parentDir/$siteName/assets/layouts",
];

// iterate each directory 
foreach($dirs as $dir) {

    // and verify that mkdir was called with that argument only once
    $fileSystemMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('mkdir')
        ->with($this->equalTo($dir));
}
```

The method being tested

```
public function createSite($siteName) {

    $fileSystem = $this->fileSystem;
    $parentDir = $this->parentDir;

    $componentsDir = "$parentDir/$siteName/assets/components";
    $layoutsDir = "$parentDir/$siteName/assets/layouts";
    $mediaDir = "$parentDir/$siteName/content/media";
    $sectionsDir = "$parentDir/$siteName/assets/sections";

    if (!$fileSystem->exists($componentsDir)) {
        $fileSystem->mkdir($componentsDir);
    }

    if (!$fileSystem->exists($layoutsDir)) {
        $fileSystem->mkdir($layoutsDir);
    }
```

However, the test fails:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'/path/to/parent/best-widgets/assets/layouts'
+'/path/to/parent/best-widgets/assets/components'
```

Hopefully it makes sense what I'm trying to. Does the once() not take into consideration the with() argument? I don't know how to just check the method was called once *with each argument*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `withConsecutive`:

```
$fileSystemMock->expects($this->exactly(count($dirs)))
  ->method('mkdir')
  ->withConsecutive(...array_map(function (string $dir) { 
     return [$this->equalTo($dir)]; 
  }, $dirs));
```

`withConsecutive` expects one parameter for each set of argument expectations, so `array_map` combined with the unpacking operator comes in handy.

Note that this should only pass if the calls are made in same order defined by the `$dirs` array. It seems a bit harder to pull off otherwise (btw, a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4026) was recently created about it).

Bonus PHP 7.4 version of the above:

```
$fileSystemMock->expects($this->exactly(count($dirs)))
  ->method('mkdir')
  ->withConsecutive(...array_map(fn(string $dir) => [$this->equalTo($dir)], $dirs));
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this might have to do. My only concern is that it depends on the calls being in a given order which I'm not too bothered about and don't want my method to strictly adhere to order defined in the test. I felt it makes my tests a little brittle. But, it seems I might not have a choice as I can't find exactly what I'm after.

Comment: There must be a workaround; I'll dig deeper later/tomorrow as I'm also curious about that, and I'll make sure to let you know if I find any clean solution (if someone else hasn't answered before then).

Comment: No problem. I think you suggestion is good enough for the issue I was having so will accept it. If you do discover anything though yeh would be great to hear and test it out. Thanks